# Bug when using conditional on Assets field value, followed by regular Grid tag

Tags: assets, grid, bug

I am using EE 2.10.1, with Assets 2.6.

I'm getting a very strange bug in my template. I have an assets image field, and a grid field that contains an Assets column.

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: grid_field_id

Filename: assets/ft.assets.php

Line Number: 1484
```

and

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: col_id

Filename: assets/ft.assets.php

Line Number: 1485
```

and

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: grid_row_id

Filename: assets/ft.assets.php

Line Number: 1486
```

Here is my template code. I have reduced it to be as simple as possible and still throw the error.

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel="products"
    status="not closed"
    require_entry="yes"
    disable="member_data|category_fields|pagination|categories"
    limit="1"
    }

    <img 
        src="{product_display_image:url}" 
        alt="{if product_display_image:alt_text}{product_display_image:alt_text}{if:else}{title} image{/if}"
        class="img-responsive" 
        itemprop="image" />



    {product_downloads}
        {product_downloads:file:title}
    {/product_downloads}


{/exp:channel:entries}
```

If I remove either the `{if product_display_image:alt_text}{product_display_image:alt_text}` conditional, or the `{product_downloads}` loop, the errors go away.

What's going on! How can I fix this?!

Here are the settings on the two fields:
[image: Assets image field settings]

[image: Product downloads grid field settings]

Comment: Anybuddy having this issue, or have any fix?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this error too. No conditional involved, but an Assets image field followed by a Grid field with an Assets image in one column. Same version of EE and Assets. I put the Grid field into an embed to get it to work. Not ideal but working.